# Extract data from a XML TEI file

Tags: xml, xslt, tei

I am finishing the encoding of a novel using a TEI XML file. I'd like to extract using XSLT the characters of each chapter, tagged as:

```
<name type="character" key="nameofthecharacter">Name</name>
```

Here is the structure:

```html
  </teiHeader>
    <text>
      <body>
        <div n='firstchapter' type='chapter'>
           <head>title</head>
              <p><name type="character" key="Sam">Sam</name> is a character        
              </p>
        </div>
        <div n='secondchapter' type='chapter'>
           <head>title</head>
              <p><name type="character" key="Elody">Elody</name>                           is a character
    </body>
  </text>
</TEI>
```

I tried basic XSLT like:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="1.0">
         <xsl:output method="text"/>
         <xsl:template match="/TEI/text/body/div[@type = 'book']"/>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="name[@type = "character"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But seems not the correct syntax to use. Any suggestions?

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in apply-templates syntaxis, and it looks like you need to match div with @type='chapter' and apply templates for descendant element *name* with @type = 'character'

In this case XSLT code should be changed like so:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="1.0">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>

     <xsl:template match="/TEI/text/body/div[@type = 'chapter']">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::name[@type = 'character']"/>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```